# Плагин jQuery для поиска элемента

Tags: jquery

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, существует ли какой-нибудь плагин, который по ID находит элемент на странице и позиционирует под ним (по центру) блок (окно предупреждения).

Необходимо решить данную задачу, не добавляя на станицу лишние элементы.

Вот макет:

[image: макет]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Alex83](/users/8823/alex83), [30 тултипов](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/).

Answer (score 2):

Да. Этот плагин называется [ядро](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset). =)))

```
offset = $('#element_id').offset();
//offset.top - Y координата
//offset.left - X координата
```

К Y надо прибавить высоту, к X - половину ширины.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду изучать.